# Create consumer dynamically spring kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I am creating a service which talks to another service in order to identify kafka topics to be listened to. The kafka topics may have different key and value types. Hence, I want to dynamically create different kafka consumers for each configuration(topic, key type, value type) where the configurations are known only at runtime. However in spring kafka, I don't see ways to pass all these parameters dynamically(at least I am not aware of any). How should I go ahead with this.

Comment: How about one consumer using `ByteArrayDeserializer`, then dynamically call different deserialization methods in the consumption method?

Comment: In Kafka, the consumer consumes all messages from a topic, and your consumer is part of a consumer group. There is no way you could say I wanted to consume messages based on message attribute(s). So if you think your messages/events are different types, then you should consider topic per event type. Otherwise, you can have one consumer group and multiple message processors to pick up runtime upon message arrival. Runtime polymorphism should be the answer, I would think.

Comment: @SanjuThomasI think my question created some confusion. One topic only has one type of data but different topics will have different type of data. My problem in to spin up a new consumer with the newly identified topic and its key type value type information.

Comment: @OneCricketeer how to configure the topics also dynamically then ?

Comment: You'd have to start a new thread for each consumer instance. My comment was more that the config doesnt need changed for each type of data

Answer (score 4):

Simply create a new listener container at runtime.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/kafka/receiving-messages/message-listener-container.html

If you are using Spring Boot, you can use the `ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory` that it automatically configures, to create containers; if not, just create and initialize the containers manually.

Comment: Hi Gary, do you have a snippet? I was looking for the same implementation for Spring Boot2

Comment: There are several examples here; see this answer for some links https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71471941/spring-kafka-multiple-topic-for-one-class-dynamically/71483489#71483489

Comment: Links go out-of-date.  It would be better if you could provide an actual example here rather than a link.

Comment: With all due respect, the links in that comment are to other answers here, which have actual examples.