# Spring Kafka multiple topic for one class dynamically

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, consumer

I recently wanted to add a new behavior in my project that uses spring-kafka.

The idea is really simple :

- App1 create a new scenario name "SCENARIO_1" and publish this string in the topic "NEW_SCENARIO"
- App1 publish some message on topic "APP2-SCENARIO_1" and "APP3-SCENARIO_1"
- App2 (group-id=app2) listens on NEW_SCENARIO and creates a new consumer<Object,String> listening on a new topic "APP2-SCENARIO_1"
- App3 (group-id=app3) listens on NEW_SCENARIO and creates a new consumer<Object,String> listening on a new topic "APP3-SCENARIO_1"

The goal is to create dynamically new topics and consumer. I cannot use spring kafka annotation since I need it to be dynamic so I did this :

```
    @KafkaListener(topics = ScenarioTopics.NEW_SCENARIO)
    public void receive(final String topic) {
        logger.info("Get new scenario " + topic + ", creating new consumer");

        TopicPartitionOffset topicPartitionOffset = new TopicPartitionOffset(
                "APP2_" + topic, 1, 0L);

        ContainerProperties containerProps = new ContainerProperties(topicPartitionOffset);
        containerProps.setMessageListener((MessageListener<Object, String>) message -> {
            // process my message
        });

        KafkaMessageListenerContainer<Object, String> container = new KafkaMessageListenerContainer<>(kafkaPeopleConsumerFactory, containerProps);
        container.start();
    }
```

And this does not work. I'm missing probably something, but I can't figure what.

Here I have some logs that tells me that the leader is not available, which is weird since I got the new scenario event.

```
        2022-03-14 18:08:26.057  INFO 21892 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.l.b.v.c.c.i.k.KafkaScenarioListener    : Get new scenario W4BdDBEowY, creating new consumer
        2022-03-14 18:08:26.061  INFO 21892 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig    : ConsumerConfig values:
        allow.auto.create.topics = true
        [...lot of things...]
        value.deserializer = class org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer

        2022-03-14 18:08:26.067  INFO 21892 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka version: 3.0.0
        2022-03-14 18:08:26.067  INFO 21892 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka commitId: 8cb0a5e9d3441962
        2022-03-14 18:08:26.067  INFO 21892 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka startTimeMs: 1647277706067
        2022-03-14 18:08:26.068  INFO 21892 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer     : [Consumer clientId=consumer-people-creator-2, groupId=people-creator] Subscribed to partition(s): PEOPLE_W4BdDBEowY-1
        2022-03-14 18:08:26.072  INFO 21892 --- [           -C-1] o.a.k.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer     : [Consumer clientId=consumer-people-creator-2, groupId=people-creator] Seeking to offset 0 for partition PEOPLE_W4BdDBEowY-1
        2022-03-14 18:08:26.081  WARN 21892 --- [           -C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-people-creator-2, groupId=people-creator] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 2 : {PEOPLE_W4BdDBEowY=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE}
        2022-03-14 18:08:26.081  INFO 21892 --- [           -C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata        : [Consumer clientId=consumer-people-creator-2, groupId=people-creator] Cluster ID: ebyKy-RVSRmUDaaeQqMaQg
        2022-03-14 18:18:04.882  WARN 21892 --- [           -C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-people-creator-2, groupId=people-creator] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 5314 : {PEOPLE_W4BdDBEowY=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE}
        2022-03-14 18:18:04.997  WARN 21892 --- [           -C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-people-creator-2, groupId=people-creator] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 5315 : {PEOPLE_W4BdDBEowY=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE}
```

How do I create dynamically a kafka consumer on a topic ? I think I do it very wrong, but I searched a lot and really didn't find anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several answers here about dynamically creating containers...

[Trigger one Kafka consumer by using values of another consumer In Spring Kafka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69134055/trigger-one-kafka-consumer-by-using-values-of-another-consumer-in-spring-kafka/69134203#69134203)

[Kafka Consumer in spring can I re-assign partitions programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69465733/kafka-consumer-in-spring-can-i-re-assign-partitions-programmatically/69466302#69466302)
[Create consumer dynamically spring kafka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67042433/create-consumer-dynamically-spring-kafka/67059213#67059213)

[Dynamically start and off KafkaListener just to load previous messages at the start of a session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61950229/dynamically-start-and-off-kafkalistener-just-to-load-previous-messages-at-the-st/61957619#61957619)

Comment: The first link helped me. I was creating a new KafkaContainerFactory, when I should have use the bean already created by Kafka.